# Set column value to null if another column value is false

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using the SQL Server Management Studio. I already created a table [PatientsRecords] which data type is date. Under this table, there is a column [DisChargedDate]. And I just added another column [IsDischarged] which data type is bit. I want to do something so that every time inserting into [PatientsRecords] table, if the [IsDischarged] value is 0(means the patient has not really left). So no matter what the value of the [DisChargedDate] is, it will be set to null.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: When selecting data from the table, you could just add that logic to whatever query you're using instead of modifying the table... But if you really want to modify the table whenever that bit column gets set, perhaps look into what a "trigger" does in sql.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to change the insert query rather than going for triggers as these could block your table and will slow down your inserts without giving any advantage.

```
insert into dbo.PatientsRecords (DisChargedDate,IsDischarged)
select
IsDischarged
case when IsDischarged = 0 then null else DisChargedDate end as DisChargedDate
from YourSourceTable
```

if you use code to insert into the table then wrap the snippet above into an insert procedure and call it from your code handing over the necessary parameters